# proof of co-area formula and level set

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

How to proof the co-area formula on surfaces:

Let for each $t \in [0,T]$, $\phi( t,\cdot) : {\bar \Omega} \rightarrow R$
be Lipschitz continuous and assume that for each $r \in (
 \textrm{inf}_{\Omega} \phi, \textrm{sup}_{\Omega} \phi)$ the level set
$\Gamma_r = \{x|\phi(x,\cdot)=r\}$ is a smooth $d$-dimensional hypersurface
 in $R^{d+1}$. Suppose $u : {\bar \Omega} \rightarrow R$ is
continuous and integrable. Then
\begin{equation}
\int^{\textrm{sup}_{\Omega}}_{\textrm{inf}_{\Omega}} \left(
\int_{\Gamma_r} u \right) d r = \int_{\Omega} u |\nabla \phi|.
\end{equation}

This formula can be found in G. Dziuk and C.M. Elliott. An Eulerian approach to transport and diffusion on
evolving implicit surfaces. Computing and Visualization in Science, 13(1):17–28,
2010.

Comment: I do not see a direct prove for this particular instance. One must use the coarea formula in general. So, basically your question  is about proof of coarea formula for real-valued Lipschitz maps.